# How do I use Feeds Tamper to process multiple CSV columns into a single field?

Tags: 9, feeds

I have a CSV file that I import into my site using [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper).

The CSV file has columns like

- URL path
- Favorite vegetable
- Favorite fruit
- Favorite pasta

In Drupal, my content type has a [JSON Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/json_field), and I want to import "Favorite vegetable", "Favorite fruit", and "Favorite pasta" into the JSON field.

**Is there a way to map all three favorites columns in the CSV file to the Drupal JSON field and combine their values in a Tamper plugin?**  I can't find any way to pull in data from multiple sources (the three CSV columns) in a Tamper plugin.

Here's the structure of a Tamper plugin.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\tamper\Plugin\Tamper;

use Drupal\tamper\Annotation\Tamper;
use Drupal\tamper\TamperableItemInterface;
use Drupal\tamper\TamperBase;

/**
 * Plugin implementation for CSV import. Copied from the encode plugin.
 *
 * @Tamper(
 *   id = "json_import",
 *   label = @Translation("JSON Import"),
 *   description = @Translation("Custom import for JSON."),
 *   category = "Text",
 *   handle_multiples = TRUE
 * )
 */
class JsonImport extends TamperBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    $config = parent::defaultConfiguration();
    return $config;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function tamper($data, TamperableItemInterface $item = NULL) {
    return $data;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's the correct way to do this.

`getSource()` will return an array with keys for all the CSV columns.

The column names are processed as follows:

- single words: Capitalization is kept. (**yellow**, **wEiRd**
- multiple words: Spaces are replaced with _, and all lowercase. (**Meta Tag** becomes **meta_tag**)

  ```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function tamper($data, TamperableItemInterface $item = NULL) {
    $csv_columns = $item->getSource();

    $json = [];
    $json['favoriteFruit'] = $csv_columns['favorite_fruit'];
    $json['favoriteVegetable'] = $csv_columns['favorite_vegetable'];
    $json['favoritePasta'] = $csv_columns['favorite_pasta'];
    $encoded_json = json_encode($json);
    return $encoded_json;
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't figured out how to access multiple CSV columns, but one workaround is to use Excel or other spreadsheet software to create a new column and generate the JSON values in Excel.  This is not a good approach because you have to do all the escaping in Excel, which is not fun and error prone.

For example, in Excel, you can use a formula like this:

```
=CONCAT("{"+CHAR(34)+"favoriteFruit"+CHAR(34)+":"+CHAR(34)+J3+CHAR(34)+","+CHAR(34)+"favoriteVegetable"+CHAR(34)+":"++CHAR(34)+K3+CHAR(34)+","+CHAR(34)+"favoritePasta"+CHAR(34)+":"+CHAR(34)+C3+CHAR(34)+"}")
```

Then, in Feeds Tamper, you need to add the **Encode** plugin and "Decode JSON" followed by the **Encode** plugin again with "Encode JSON".  If your JSON doesn't have any mistakes, it will be imported into Drupal.